# Paste Transposing Array using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please take a look on this code. Below macro copy and past range of data (using array).
The only thing is I need to adjust is transposing this array. For the some reason transposing array looks as attached picture. Transposing, but not fully. Thanks for support.

[image]

```
Sub copy_data_for_sap_input_sheet()
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
    Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
    Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook
    Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet
        
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsCopyTo = Sheets("sap_input")

        If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
            Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets(1)
        End If
    
    wsCopyFrom.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    oarray = wsCopyFrom.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    wsCopyTo.Activate
    wsCopyTo.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(oarray), UBound(oarray, 2)) = Application.Transpose(oarray)
    wbCopyFrom.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: flip the `Resize`: `Resize(UBound(oarray,2), UBound(oarray))`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you. Works perfectly